# How is it possible to replace the HOC and call it only once and just change the prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a header Higher order component for my project that has been used several times, and its props (such as whether header links should be displayed or not) have been determined every time. My goal is to call it only once and, if necessary, not to use HOC. How can I set props for each component?

its my HOC:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Header } from '@@ting/molecules/Header'

export type WithHeaderProps = {   showLinks?: boolean  
 hideOnScrollUp?: boolean   stickyTransparent?: boolean }
 
 export const withHeader =   <T extends any>(headerProps?:
 WithHeaderProps) =>   (Component: React.ComponentType<T>) =>   (props:
 T) => {
     const { showLinks = true, hideOnScrollUp = false, stickyTransparent = true } = headerProps || {}
     return (
       <>
         <Header showLinks={showLinks} hideOnScrollUp={hideOnScrollUp} stickyTransparent={stickyTransparent} />
         <Component {...props} />
       </>
     )   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change Header properties, I used context and useEffect.
I created it as a custom hook:

```
  useHeader:  
      useEffect(() => {
        setHeaderContext({ showLinks: true, hideOnScrollUp: isCinemaMode, stickyTransparent: isCinemaMode })
        return () => {
          setHeaderContext({ showLinks: true, hideOnScrollUp: false, stickyTransparent: true })
        }
      }, [isCinemaMode, setHeaderContext])
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your HOC using `React.memo` to make it pure component.
Also you need to pass prop variables using `useMemo` hook and functions using `useCallback` hook, those which regenerate on each render.
This will allows REACT to memorize them, Thus prevents wasted renders, or create custom render condition.

`React.memo` has two args.